# Cordova CLI: plugins downloaded every time

Tags: cordova

Is there a way to prevent repeated plugin downloads on `cordova build` ?
every time it downloads my 3rd party plugins which takes some time.

the plugin is specified like this in the `config.xml`:

```
<plugin name="ADBMobile" spec="https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/mobile-services#v4.5.6-iOS" />
```

Comment: try adding --save at the end of the install command (cordova plugin add xxx --save)

Comment: that is already the case. I think this is rather a caching issue. btw, the same happens when using an NPM based plugin. I wonder why it tries to refetch the plugin.